# How to controling an existing MDI child from an external form

Tags: c#, forms, controls, mdi

MainWindow is the MDI parent. WebPage is the MDI child.  PageTitle is the external form

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PD2mL.png

I would like to use the PageTitle form to control the active WebPage MDI form (Active MDI child).

Comment: Save a reference to it. You might want to save it statically, and you might want to save it as a member of MainWindow, to which you'll hold a reference in the PageTitle form. Once you have a reference to the instance, you just gotta publicize any functionality you want, and you'll be able to call it.

Comment: Can you show me how to save a reference in this situation!

Comment: Easiest way is to pass `this` to the constructor of the PageTitle form.

Comment: Thank you very much.  The problem is solved!